# Internal memory full

Tags: factory-reset

I am using Micromax tablet for the last 4 years. As internal memory had become full, I removed many apps. Still same was the problem. I thought by factory res-setting the tablet, the problem would go away. Even after factory reset, it shows    internal memory is full even after factory reset . What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You might do `Hard Reset` that will help you. Sometimes `Normal Reset` Does not work.

1. First of all switch off the device by pressing the **Power** button.
2. In the next step hold down **Volume Up + Power button** for about 10 seconds.
3. You can release held keys when you see the **Android Robot**.
4. To enter the **Recovery Mode** hold down the **Power** key for a short while.
5. From the menu choose **"Wipe Data/Factory Reset"** by using **Volume** buttons to scroll and Power button to select options.
6. Tap "yes" to confirm the operation if you are certain you want to clear all your data.
7. Use the Power button to accept the option **"reboot system now"**.
   Well done!

This will surely help you. otherwise, your hard disk might get somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

- Micromax tabs usually come with multiple bloatware, if you are ok with root, then you can remove all those apps. It should free up significant memory.
- Installing and moving apps to SD card will also help.
- Remove unused/ less frequently used apps

Hope this helps